Secondary X axis using plotly
I need to create a secondary x-axis (without creating a primary x-axis) with primary y-axis. Could anybody give suggestions? I tried to put side='top'. it does not work.
fig = go.Figure()

  # Add traces to the figure (primary x-axis and primary y-axis)
  fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1, mode='lines', name='Sin', line=dict(color='blue')))
  fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2, mode='lines', name='Cos', line=dict(color='red')))

  # Add secondary x-axis (xaxis2)
  fig.update_layout(
    xaxis2=dict(
        title='Secondary X-axis', 
        overlaying='x',           
        side='top',              
        showgrid=False,           
        zeroline=False 
      )


This is accomplished by adding an axis specification for each graph. xaxis='x2' See the reference for details. fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1, mode='lines', name='Sin', line=dict(color='blue'), xaxis='x2')) fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2, mode='lines', name='Cos', line=dict(color='red'), xaxis='x2'))
